# C# Define custom UnmanagedType for the MarshalAs attribute class

Tags: c#, marshalling, unmanaged, unix-timestamp

is it possible to define a custom UnmanagedType for the MarshalAs attribute class?
Specifically I want to convert a long int unix time into a DateTime type. Something like this:

```
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LongTimeUnix)]
public DateTime Time;
```

Where do I have to put the custom LongTimeUnix enumeration type and where to put the time conversion code:

```
public static DateTime ConvertUnix2DateTime(long timeStamp)
{
        DateTime DT = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        DT = DT.AddSeconds(timeStamp);
        return DT;
}
```

When transferring the data with

```
(SomeStruct)Marshal.PtrToStructure(
 IntPtr,
 typeof(SomeStruct));
```

I want that the long time unix is automatically converted with the code sinppet above.
Do I have to inherit from the MarshalAs class and write the conversion into this class?
Thanks, Juergen

**Update**
Here is the custom marshaller:

```
class MarshalTest : ICustomMarshaler
{
    public void CleanUpManagedData(object ManagedObj)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void CleanUpNativeData(IntPtr pNativeData)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public int GetNativeDataSize()
    {
        return 8;
    }

    public IntPtr MarshalManagedToNative(object ManagedObj)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public object MarshalNativeToManaged(IntPtr pNativeData)
    {
        long UnixTime = 0;
        try
        {
            UnixTime = Marshal.ReadInt64(pNativeData);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

           QFXLogger.Error(e, "MarshalNativeToManaged");
        }
        DateTime DT = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        DT = DT.AddSeconds(UnixTime);
        return DT;
    }
 }
```

Here is the class definition:

```
unsafe public struct MT5ServerAttributes
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Last known server time.
    /// </summary>
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.CustomMarshaler, MarshalTypeRef = typeof(MarshalTest))]
    public DateTime CurrentTime;

    //[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U8)]
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.CustomMarshaler, MarshalTypeRef = typeof(MarshalTest))]
    public DateTime TradeTime;

 }
```

And finally the code to marshal the data from unmanaged memory:

```
try
{
   MT5ServerAttributes MT5SrvAttributes = (MT5ServerAttributes)Marshal.PtrToStructure(mMT5Proxy.MT5InformationProxy.ServerData,
                                                                    typeof(MT5ServerAttributes));
}
catch (Exception e)
{

QFXLogger.Error(e, "ConsumeCommand inner");
}
```

When running this the following excpetion is thrown(which is not a direct exception ot PtrToStructure!)
Cannot marshal field 'CurrentTime' of type 'QFX_DLL.MT5ServerAttributes': Invalid managed/unmanaged type combination (the DateTime class must be paired with Struct).
Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot add your own to the enumeration, but you can use `UnmanagedType.CustomMarshaler`. To specify that you want to marshal it using a custom type.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w22x2hw6.aspx) has an entire section dedicated to this.

You would end up doing something along these lines:

```
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.CustomMarshaler, MarshalTypeRef = typeof(MyCustomMarshaler))]
public DateTime Time;
```

Then implement MyCustomMarshaler as [`ICustomMarshaler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.icustommarshaler.aspx).

Comment: Does this really works ? I am trying the same and it fails because you can't use `CustomMarshaler` on a class member. As far as I can tell `CustomMarshaler` only works for function parameters (and that's a pain).

Comment: Nope, no joy for me either @J.N..  I suspect from his comment that @Juergen marked this as an answer before actually trying it.  If you skip the step of calling `Marshal.SizeOf` and go directly to the `Marshal.PtrToStructure` call, you'll get the error **"Custom marshalers cannot be used on fields of structures."**  That pretty much says it can't be done.